# Create Shipping Cart Rules

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Create Shipping Cart Rules

Product must not not be from category X,Y and Z and order total should be greater then $150

Comment: This question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

for adding shopping cart rules go to promotion->shopping cart rules->yourrules and refer below image.
[image: Below image define how to add category cond in shopping cart rules]

[image: Other image show order total condition]

Comment: Thanks for help... can i add category id in like this ...  x,y,z

Comment: @rajppari as i know its created by magento when we create any category.